# Node.js check if path is file or directory

Tags: node.js, path, directory, filesystems, fs

I can't seem to get any search results that explain how to do this.

All I want to do is be able to know if a given path is a file or a directory (folder).

Comment: Note that there are also symlinks, which can link to files, link to directories, or be broken. There are also other kinds of paths besides files, directories, and symlinks. So you have to be careful not to just check for "directory" and assume everything else is "file", etc. And you have to think about whether you want symlinks to be followed transparently. One gotcha is that a `Dirent` returned by `scandir()` and a `Stat` returned by `stat()` both have `isFile()` and `isDirectory()` methods but the former don't follow symlinks and the latter do.

Answer (score 904, accepted):

The following should tell you.  From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats):

```js
fs.lstatSync(path_string).isDirectory()
```

> Objects returned from fs.stat() and fs.lstat() are of this type.
>
> ```js
> stats.isFile()
> stats.isDirectory()
> stats.isBlockDevice()
> stats.isCharacterDevice()
> stats.isSymbolicLink() // (only valid with fs.lstat())
> stats.isFIFO()
> stats.isSocket()
> ```

#### NOTE:

The **above solution** will `throw` an `Error` if; for ex, the `file` or `directory` doesn't exist.

If you want a `true` or `false` approach, try `fs.existsSync(dirPath) && fs.lstatSync(dirPath).isDirectory();` as mentioned by Joseph in the comments below.

Comment: Note that the asynchronous version is usually preferable if you care about general app performance.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the directory or file does not exist, then you will get an error back.

Comment: ```let isDirExists = fs.existsSync(dirPath) && fs.lstatSync(dirPath).isDirectory();```

Comment: Keep in mind that if file or directory does not exists it will throw exception that needs to be caught otherwise it will cause abnormal exit.

Comment: @JossefHarush What happens if the file gets deleted between those steps?

Comment: Does `isDirectory` return true if it's a symlinked directory?

Comment: I find it odd that when they first made lstat they didnt just include an exists() function in there? I guess this is why node_modules is deeper than a black hole.

Comment: Why is everyone using `fs.lstat()`? The docs say it will always be `false`: "If the `<fs.Stats>` object was obtained from `fs.lstat()`, this method [`<fs.Stats>.isDirectory()`] will always return `false`. This is because `fs.lstat()` returns information about a symbolic link itself and not the path it resolves to."

Comment: @snickle `fs.stat` will resolve all symlinks, and return stats for the real path. so it depends on the use case

Answer (score 99):

### Update: Node.Js >= 10

We can use the new [fs.promises](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) API

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;

(async() => {
    const stat = await fs.lstat('test.txt');
    console.log(stat.isFile());
})().catch(console.error)
```

---

### Any Node.Js version

Here's how you would detect if a path is a file or a directory **asynchronously**, which is the recommended approach in node.
 using [fs.lstat](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_lstat_path_callback)

```
const fs = require("fs");

let path = "/path/to/something";

fs.lstat(path, (err, stats) => {

    if(err)
        return console.log(err); //Handle error

    console.log(`Is file: ${stats.isFile()}`);
    console.log(`Is directory: ${stats.isDirectory()}`);
    console.log(`Is symbolic link: ${stats.isSymbolicLink()}`);
    console.log(`Is FIFO: ${stats.isFIFO()}`);
    console.log(`Is socket: ${stats.isSocket()}`);
    console.log(`Is character device: ${stats.isCharacterDevice()}`);
    console.log(`Is block device: ${stats.isBlockDevice()}`);
});
```

---

Note when using the synchronous API:

> When using the synchronous form any exceptions are immediately thrown.
>   You can use try/catch to handle exceptions or allow them to bubble up.

```
try{
     fs.lstatSync("/some/path").isDirectory()
}catch(e){
   // Handle error
   if(e.code == 'ENOENT'){
     //no such file or directory
     //do something
   }else {
     //do something else
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this still considered experimental as of Mar. 2020?  Where can we look to see? -- Oops I see when I click the link above that it's now stable (which implies no longer experimental).

Answer (score 36):

Seriously, question exists five years and no nice facade?

```
import {lstatSync} from 'fs';
/**
 * @param {string} path - The path.
 * @returns {boolean} Whether path is a directory, otherwise always false.
 */
function isDir(path) {
  try {
    const stat = lstatSync(path);
    return stat.isDirectory();
  } catch (e) {
    // lstatSync throws an error if path doesn't exist
    return false;
  }
}
console.log("Is /tmp      a dir?", isDir("/tmp")      ? 'Yes!' : 'No!');
console.log("Is /root     a dir?", isDir("/root")     ? 'Yes!' : 'No!');
console.log("Is /dev      a dir?", isDir("/dev")      ? 'Yes!' : 'No!');
console.log("Is /dev/null a dir?", isDir("/dev/null") ? 'Yes!' : 'No!');
```

Outputs on a unix-like system:

```
Is /tmp      a dir? Yes!
Is /root     a dir? Yes!
Is /dev      a dir? Yes!
Is /dev/null a dir? No!
```

Comment: `[Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/tmp/snap.skype']` when I provide `/tmp/` which is a dir and accessible.

Comment: @MarinosAn I would assume you don't have read permission for that file, so it fails.

Comment: Nice facade! Suggested slight mod in the catch clause: return null instead of false. That way a calling function could distinguish if the name is a file or doesn't exist, which would otherwise require another lstat call.

Comment: @tgoneil Thank you for the suggestion - I will keep it as it is, a facade doesn't really care about micro optimizations, just about simplicity. The function is called `isDir` after all and not `isDirOrFileOrDoesntExist`.

Answer (score 22):

If you need this when iterating over a directory (Because that's how I've found this question):

Since Node 10.10+, `fs.readdir` has a [`withFileTypes`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreaddirpath-options-callback) option which makes it return directory entry [`fs.Dirent`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/fs.html#class-fsdirent) instead of strings. Directory entries has a `name` property, and useful methods such as `isDirectory` or `isFile`, so you don't need to call `fs.lstat` explicitly.

```js
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

// ./my-dir has two subdirectories: dir-a, and dir-b

const dirEntries = await fs.readdir('./my-dir', { withFileTypes: true });

// let's filter all directories in ./my-dir

const onlyDirs = dirEntries.filter(de => de.isDirectory()).map(de => de.name);

// onlyDirs is now [ 'dir-a', 'dir-b' ]
```

Answer (score 16):

Depending on your needs, you can probably rely on node's `path` module.

You may not be able to hit the filesystem (e.g. the file hasn't been created yet) and tbh you probably want to avoid hitting the filesystem unless you really need the extra validation. If you can make the assumption that what you are checking for follows `.<extname>` format, just look at the name.

Obviously if you are looking for a file without an extname you will need to hit the filesystem to be sure. But keep it simple until you need more complicated.

```
const path = require('path');

function isFile(pathItem) {
  return !!path.extname(pathItem);
}
```

Comment: Obviously this won't work in all situations but it's much quicker and easier than the other answers if you can make the needed assumptions.

Comment: the directory could be named `folder.txt` and this would say its a file, or the file could be `LICENSE` with no extensin

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that I use. Nobody is making use of `promisify` and `await/async` feature in this post so I thought I would share.

```
const promisify = require('util').promisify;
const lstat = promisify(require('fs').lstat);

async function isDirectory (path) {
  try {
    return (await lstat(path)).isDirectory();
  }
  catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Note : I don't use `require('fs').promises;` because it has been experimental for one year now, better not rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above check if a filesystem contains a path that is a file or directory. But it doesn't identify if a given path alone is a file or directory.

> The answer is to identify directory-based paths using "/." like --> "/c/dos/run/." <-- trailing period.

Like a path of a directory or file that has not been written yet. Or a path from a different computer. Or a path where both a file and directory of the same name exists.

```
// /tmp/
// |- dozen.path
// |- dozen.path/.
//    |- eggs.txt
//
// "/tmp/dozen.path" !== "/tmp/dozen.path/"
//
// Very few fs allow this. But still. Don't trust the filesystem alone!

// Converts the non-standard "path-ends-in-slash" to the standard "path-is-identified-by current "." or previous ".." directory symbol.
function tryGetPath(pathItem) {
    const isPosix = pathItem.includes("/");
    if ((isPosix && pathItem.endsWith("/")) ||
        (!isPosix && pathItem.endsWith("\\"))) {
        pathItem = pathItem + ".";
    }
    return pathItem;
}
// If a path ends with a current directory identifier, it is a path! /c/dos/run/. and c:\dos\run\.
function isDirectory(pathItem) {
    const isPosix = pathItem.includes("/");
    if (pathItem === "." || pathItem ==- "..") {
        pathItem = (isPosix ? "./" : ".\\") + pathItem;
    }
    return (isPosix ? pathItem.endsWith("/.") || pathItem.endsWith("/..") : pathItem.endsWith("\\.") || pathItem.endsWith("\\.."));
} 
// If a path is not a directory, and it isn't empty, it must be a file
function isFile(pathItem) {
    if (pathItem === "") {
        return false;
    }
    return !isDirectory(pathItem);
}
```

Node version: v11.10.0 - Feb 2019

> Last thought: Why even hit the filesystem?

Comment: what if the folder name has a dot at the end of it, like `.git` or even `myFolder.txt`?

Comment: You have to understand posix filepath conventions (which windows, in part, adheres to since Windows is posix complient in the kernel level). Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980255/should-a-directory-path-variable-end-with-a-trailing-slash and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Path_(computing)#Filepath_Misconceptions

Comment: Didn't really answer this did I? .git and myFolder.txt can be either a folder or a file. You don't know until you check. Since folders are also considered file, you cannot have a folder and a file named the same. .git/. and myFolder.txt/. are both folders. .git/ and myFolder.txt/ are all the files within that folder. man readline documents this (obscurely). The lone . is special. files/folders containing . are not.

Comment: . and .. are both special

Answer (score -1):

**Function that returns type**

I like coffee

```
type: (uri)-> (fina) ->
  fs.lstat uri, (erro,stats) ->
    console.log {erro} if erro
    fina(
      stats.isDirectory() and "directory" or
      stats.isFile() and "document" or
      stats.isSymbolicLink() and "link" or
      stats.isSocket() and "socket" or
      stats.isBlockDevice() and "block" or
      stats.isCharacterDevice() and "character" or
      stats.isFIFO() and "fifo"
    )
```

usage:

```
dozo.type("<path>") (type) ->
  console.log "type is #{type}"
```