# Node.js check if path is directory error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15630832/2908941) to allow me to check if a given file path is a directory, however I get the following error:

```
fs.js:679
  return binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '.DS_Store'
    at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:679:18)
```

I figured that maybe it couldn't handle hidden files well, so, after failing to find a more elegant solution, I checked if the first character in the file name was a '.'. However, the program then crashed on another file:

```
fs.js:679
  return binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'README.md'
    at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:679:18)
```

Why does `fs.lstatSync()` seem to error for such common files, and how can I make it work (correctly evaluate if the given path is a directory)?

Comment: are you giving the directory path only or a file path?

Comment: @NitishDhar I give it the path to what could be either a file or a directory. The purpose of the method is to determine which type it is.

Comment: Are you sure that the path exists 100% of the time? This error seems to be stemming from the fact that there is neither a file nor a folder at that path, so maybe you should check to see if it exists first before running `lstat`.

Comment: Looks like your giving `lstatSync()` only a filename without a path. Could it be that the files aren't in the current working directory?