# How to check if path is a directory or file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to check if the path is a file or a directory. If it's a directory then Log the directory and file separately. Later I want to send them as json object.

```
const testFolder = './data/';
fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(`FILES: ${file}`);
  })});
```

**Edit:**
If I try to this

```
fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    if (fs.statSync(file).isDirectory()) {
    console.log(`DIR: ${file}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`FILE: ${file}`)
  }
  })});
```

I get this error:

> nodejs binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path))

**Update:** Found the solution. I had to add testFolder + file like this :

```
if (fs.statSync(testFolder + file).isDirectory()) {
```

Comment: I think you used the wrong tag "java" :)

Comment: Java user: "Java (not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS)"

Comment: sorry for typo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js check if path is file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630770/node-js-check-if-path-is-file-or-directory)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630770/node-js-check-if-path-is-file-or-directory?

Comment: @Lorddirt but i m getting the error

Answer (score 4):

quick google search..

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stats = fs.statSync("c:\\dog.jpg");
console.log('is file ? ' + stats.isFile());
```

read: http://www.technicalkeeda.com/nodejs-tutorials/how-to-check-if-path-is-file-or-directory-using-nodejs

Comment: I get this error nodejs binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path))

Comment: can you give the user read permissions ?

looks like a known issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3977

Answer (score 2):

Since Node 10.10+, `fs.readdir` has `withFileTypes` option which makes it return directory entry [`fs.Dirent`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/fs.html#class-fsdirent) instead of just the filename. Directory entry contains useful methods such as `isDirectory` or `isFile`.

Your example then would be solved by:

```js
const testFolder = './data/';
fs.readdir(testFolder, { withFileTypes: true }, (err, dirEntries) => {
  dirEntries.forEach((dirEntry) => {
    const { name } = dirEntry;
    if (dirEntry.isDirectory()) {
      console.log(`DIR: ${name}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`FILE: ${name}`);
    }
  })})
```