# When to put "/" at the end of a file path

Tags: tomcat, filepath, servlet-3.0

This might be largely context based, but when is it appropriate to put the "/" at the end of a file path in Unix systems? I'm asking because I've been trying to figure out why my tomcat server wasn't bringing a page up on my browser when using the localhost:8080 port. I had been using

```
http://localhost:8080/MyProject/home
```

and it wasn't working until I finally used

```
http://localhost:8080/MyProject/home/
```

notice the "/" at the end.

So what does it mean when it has the forward slash at the end? If it makes any difference, "home" is a location I specified using the @WebServlet annotation in my servlet as

```
@WebServlet("/home/")
```

I know I put the "/" here, so it's obvious why I should have used the forward slash in my URL, but I would like to know for future use what this forward slash at the end is specifying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should a directory path variable end with a trailing slash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980255/should-a-directory-path-variable-end-with-a-trailing-slash)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me this question is more about URL design than file path.  If you don't want the trailing slash you could use

```
@WebServlet("/home")
```

For a URL design, if there is a trailing slash, that typically means that the URL you are accessing has many sub-urls and that you are retrieving the index page for that URL.  In other words, if `/home/` represents the user's home page then it should be `/home`.  If `/home/` represents the index of the user's home directory then it should be exactly as it is.

If you really are talking about file paths then you should see @Jayram's comment.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you. So then what you are saying is what the discussions that @Jayram posted is also saying; where if it ends with a trailing slash it's a directory, and if it doesn't it's a file? I'm a little confused because I can't tell if you're saying what I just said in the last sentence, or if you're saying a URL that ends with a trailing slash could still refer to a file, but there are also subdirectories in the directory containing that file. So for example if your URL is
    /MyProject/Webcontent/home/

Then there are additional subdirectories in the Webcontent directory.

Comment: I'm saying, it shouldn't end in a slash unless there are subdirectories in the /home "directory", in other words, you have /home/a, /home/b, etc.  As an example, `http://www.cad-comic.com/cad/` is always the latest web comic (the "index" in this case) while `http://www.cad-comic.com/cad/<date>` is the comic for that date (there are subdirectories under /cad)