# Should I save a path with or without a trailing slash at the end, what's the convention

Tags: php, conventions

I'm always confuse whether I should add a trailing slash at the end of a path, and often mix it up, leading to some file no found.
Example with drupal:

```
$base_theme = '/sites/all/themes/myTheme/';
```

or

```
$base_theme = '/sites/all/themes/myTheme';
```

The image path could extend the base theme:

```
$base_image = $base_theme.'images/';
```

or

```
$base_image = $base_theme.'/images';
```

Is there any convention? Or I can pick which one I prefer?

I would choose to finish all path with a trailing slash since too many slash is better than no slash.

Comment: I tend to agree with you that more is better than less since it won't break anything... I'm curious if there's any convention for this as well.

Comment: I do not add the trailing slash. My reasoning is that a folder name does not include the `/`.

Comment: Anyway, whatever way you prefer, if you start working on an ongoing project, look at how is done there. I hate when you have some paths defined with and some without a trailing slash.

Comment: See related question in programmers.SE: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/84778/trailing-forward-slash-in-directory-names-good-programming-practice

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/980255/1668200

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> **TL;DR:** There's no real convention. Trailing slash would be the more globally easy to recognize format. The important thing is that you're consistent through your design and that you convey your usage clearly.

---

There's no real convention; but there are considerations to make.

### Advantages in trailing slash:

1. Trailing slash usually indicates a folder path (or a prettified URL) whereas a file extension denotes a direct file link. (Think `example.com/home/` VS `example.com/style.css`).
2. This is usually friendlier for people coming from UNIX and such, as in the terminal a clear convention is to leave a trailing slash for directories.
3. As a programmer - adding a trailing slash will result in less-likely programmer errors; for example: accidentally adding a second slash will look ugly (`http://example.com/styles//myfile.css`) but will not break the file link. Forgetting a slash will: `http://example.com/stylesmyfile.css`, however the behavior might be confusing for query strings: `http://example.com/thread?id=1` VS `http://example.com/thread/?id=1` <- the result really depends on how you handle your `.htaccess`.

### Advantages in no trail:

1. Prettier, some might say
2. It's easier to remember and it's more readable to always add a slash when appending paths to a variable string than not. i.e. it's easier to remember `$baseURL . '/path.php'` than `$baseURL . 'path.php'`