# torch dataloader for large csv file - incremental loading

Tags: pytorch, dataloader

I am trying to write a custom torch data loader so that large CSV files can be loaded incrementally (by chunks).

I have a rough idea of how to do that. However, I keep getting some PyTorch error that I do not know how to solve.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

# Create dummy csv data
nb_samples = 110
a = np.arange(nb_samples)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['data'])
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)


# Create Dataset
class CSVDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path, chunksize, nb_samples):
        self.path = path
        self.chunksize = chunksize
        self.len = nb_samples / self.chunksize

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = next(
            pd.read_csv(
                self.path,
                skiprows=index * self.chunksize + 1,  #+1, since we skip the header
                chunksize=self.chunksize,
                names=['data']))
        x = torch.from_numpy(x.data.values)
        return x

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len


dataset = CSVDataset('data.csv', chunksize=10, nb_samples=nb_samples)
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=10, num_workers=1, shuffle=False)

for batch_idx, data in enumerate(loader):
    print('batch: {}\tdata: {}'.format(batch_idx, data))
```

I get `'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` error

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by this line:

```py
self.len = nb_samples / self.chunksize
```

When dividing using `/` the result is always a float. But you can only return an integer in the `__len__()` function. Therefore you have to round `self.len` and/or convert it to an integer. For example by simply doing this:

```py
self.len = nb_samples // self.chunksize
```

the double slash (`//`) rounds down and converts to integer.

**Edit:**
You acutally CAN return a float in `__len__()` but when calling `len(dataset)` the error will occur. So I guess `len(dataset)` is called somewhere inside the `DataLoader` class.

Comment: Many thanks for this suggestion. However, with this fix I get a new error: ```DataLoader worker (pid(s) 18357) exited unexpectedly```

Comment: this error is unrelated. But maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60101662/8909353) answer helps