# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20220904_EnduroDuLynx_Haulot_0768.jpg'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When I run this code I get this error. I don't see how this is possible given that "file" is selected by the loop. I tried with absolute paths and it's the same error. The file exists and when I delete it from my directory, it's another file it can't find. `

```
from PIL import Image
import os

width = 200
height = 300


for file in os.listdir("images"):
    # chargez l'image et redimensionnez-la
    image = Image.open(file)
    resized_image = image.resize((width, height))

    resized_image.save("images-recadre" + file)
```

`

how should i do to solve this ?

Comment: "./"+file should do it

Comment: This is because `os.listdir` just returns the file name.  You need `Image.open('images/'+file)`.  `"./"+file` will not do it; if it did, there would be no need for the `./`.

Comment: `Image.open(file)` This assumes file is in the current directory.  But it is actually in the `images` subdirectory.

Comment: [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module) is another option. ```iterdir``` as opposed to ```listdir```.

Comment: @jwal Very helpful link to migrate from `os` to `pathlib`. It's safer, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74910347/5730279).

Answer (score 0):

#### Debugging

Either research, because the `FileNotFoundError` in combination with `os.listdir` is known and answered:

- [Python raising FileNotFoundError for file name returned by os.listdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799353/python-raising-filenotfounderror-for-file-name-returned-by-os-listdir)

Or debug using print-statements and reading the docs about `os.listdir` helps.

```
from PIL import Image
import os

width = 200
height = 300


for file in os.listdir("images"):
    print("file name:", file)  # is the printed an absolute path

    # chargez l'image et redimensionnez-la
    image = Image.open(file)  # does this line throw the error?
    resized_image = image.resize((width, height))

    # does save need an absolute path?
    print("save to path:", "images-recadre" + file)
    resized_image.save("images-recadre" + file)  # needs a path-separator
```

#### Safer to use `pathlib`

As [jwal commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74909878/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-20220904-endurodulynx-h#comment132196627_74909878), use the object-oriented counterparts of `pathlib`:

- [`p = Path('images')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) to define the path instance (here as directory relative to current)
- [`Path.iterdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir) to find files in the path instance
- [`Path.absolute()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.absolute) to get the absolute-path for file-IO functions
- [`Path.joinpath(*other)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.joinpath) to add subfolders or filenames
- [`Path.name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) to return the *basename* of the file (like `picture.png`)

```
from pathlib import Path

images_folder = Path('images')
for child in images_folder.iterdir():
    print("file name:", child)  # is the printed an absolute path
    file = child.absolute()

    # chargez l'image et redimensionnez-la
    image = Image.open(file)  # does this line throw the error?
    resized_image = image.resize((width, height))

    to_path = images_folder.joinpath("images-recadre", child.name)  # join adds the path-separators
    print("saving to path:", to_path)
    resized_image.save(to_path)
```

Comment: If you are aware that this is a duplicate (and even voted to close as such), why post an answer as well? If you think you have something to add that is already covered in the other answers, you can post the answer on the duplicate from 7 years ago

Comment: @Tomerikoo I flagged as duplicate because of common `os.listdir` misconception. On the other hand instead of fixing the old functional approach with `os`, teaching migration using [sane](https://peps.python.org/pep-0428/#sane-behaviour) `pathlib` seems so suitable here.

Comment: Which is [also covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73667037/6045800) in the duplicate...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I posted my [answer on another duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74919509/5730279). Is this and the removal here what you intended with your comment?

Answer (score -1):

The file is probably not in the folder. Go to your file explorer and find the image you have. Drag it into your folder with the code. Rename the file so it is easier to type in.

Comment: The file is in the folder, because it was just returned by `os.listdir`, that's why OP tries to open it. Maybe you can find another answer by reading the docs for `os.listdir`. Hint: It says something about file names (not absolute paths).