# How can I remove directory paths listed in a text file but keep the file paths?

Tags: regex, powershell, text

I have a text file with thousands of lines, containing both directory paths and file paths.
I would like to loop through each line of the text file and remove any lines containing a directory path, and keep all lines containing a file path. An example of two lines (one directory, and one path from the text file):

```
exampleDirectoryPath/tags/10.0.0.8/tools/
exampleFilePath/tags/10.0.0.8/tools/hello.txt
```

So far, to loop through the text file, I have:

```
foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("file.txt")) {
    if ($line -match ".*/.*$") {
        $line
    }
}
```

Goal output:

```
exampleFilePath/tags/10.0.0.8/tools/hello.txt
```

Note: I do not want to hardcode file extensions. There are thousands of files to traverse and I  dont know what extensions are present, so I would like to return all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the basic logic here is easy:

```
Get-Content "file.txt" | where { $_ is a file path... }
```

It kind of depends on how you want to determine, if it's a file path

If all of your directory paths end in "/", you could simply do:

```
where { -not $_.EndsWith("/") }
```

or:

```
where { [system.io.Path]::GetFileName($_) -eq "" }
```

If not, but all of your file paths definitely have an extension, you could do:

```
where { [system.io.Path]::GetExtension($_) -ne "" }
```

If all of the paths actually exist, you could also do this:

```
where { Test-Path $_ -Type Leaf }
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed where { $_.EndsWith("/") } to where { ! $_.EndsWith("/") } - this ensured it was returning files, not folders.

Comment: While this is def a great, succinct answer, I just wanted to add that, depending on your use case, you should be careful about how much you rely on this method. See this discussion for a good primer on some of the nuances of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980255/should-a-directory-path-variable-end-with-a-trailing-slash   TL;DR - there is no way to to determine with 100% certainty whether something is or isn't a file purely from its path string, and in certain contexts, trailing slashes can mean different things. Be esp. careful if using this cross platform

Answer (score 1):

To provide a concise solution that also performs well:

```
(Get-Content -ReadCount 0 file.txt) -notmatch '\\$'
```

- Using `-ReadCount 0` with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) is a performance optimization that returns all lines in the input file as a *single array object* rather than collecting the lines one by one.

  - Additionally, `-ReadCount 0` ensures that an *array* is output even if the input file happens to have just *one* line.
- `-notmatch`, the negated form of the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch), acts as a *filter* with an *array*-valued LHS, returning the (non)matching elements (lines) (as a new array).

  - Regex `\\$` matches a verbatim `\` at the end (`$`) of each input string (line).

Note: As your question suggests, the solution above assumes that directories can be distinguished from files *formally*, based on whether the lines in the input file end in `/` or not.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would not use `regex` for this for the simple reason that, even though you may be able to validate if the path's pattern matches the pattern of a file or folder, it cannot validate if it actually exists. I would use this following your code:

```
$result = foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("file.txt"))
{
    if(([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$line).Attributes -eq 'Archive')
    {
        $line
    }
}
```